# How to diagnose a EXC_BAD_ACCESS while my App running - objective-C

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, nszombieenabled

I'm working on a 2d OpenGL ES game. I've used Clang and Instruments to find and eliminate all leaks. My app's memory usage (Live Bytes in ObjectAlloc) holds steady at around 1.5MB. However, long play sessions result in an eventual EXC_BAD_ACCESS. When I turn on NSZombieEnabled the app runs out of memory (and crashes) before the EXC_BAD_ACCESS has a chance to occur.

How else can I diagnose a EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Comment: Have you run the app within the Simulator and read the crash report (in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports), or more easily, just used the debugger, to find out where exactly the crash occurs?

Comment: Took another look at the Debugger and saw what I wasn't seeing before. So easy to miss the obvious. 

An object retained by a Timer was trying to access a weak reference to another object that had already been deallocated.

Comment: You're lucky, you've solved it. Check this out to bake your noodle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159205/nsurlcache-crashes-with-autoreleased-objects-but-leaks-otherwise